# Cuda Fortran: Data copy from cpu to gpu

Tags: cuda, fortran

I have a problem about the data copy form host to device. Here is my problem. I have an array define as

```
 real, allocatable         :: cpuArray(:,:,:)
 real, device, allocatable :: gpuArrray(:,:,:)
 allocate(cpuArray(0:imax-1,0:jmax-1,0:kmax-1))
 allocate(gpuArrray(-1:imax,-1:jmax,-1:kmax))

 !array initialiazation 
 cpuArrray = randomValue  !non 0 value

 gpuArray = 0.0  !first 0 all gpu array elements 
 gpuArrray(0:imax-1,0:jmax-1,0:kmax-1)= cpuArray
```

My expectation is that only the designated index in the gpuArray will receive data from the host however it does not work.

Could you help me find what is wrong with this?

PS: I based my my approach from this [tutorial](http://www.pgroup.com/lit/articles/insider/v2n1a3.htm) of PGI home page

--
When I set both the cpuArray and the gpuArray the same dimension, 
I get exactly the correct result.

But the current situation produces 0 for all element in the gpuArray. I modified the default value to a non zero (ie.  gpuArray = 10.0  !first 10 all gpu array elements ) but the result still 0.

Best regards,
Adjeiinfo

Comment: Do you have an actual question?

Comment: Talonmies, thank you, I addded my question.

Comment: Sorry I still don't understand. You tell us it "seems to work well", but then you want us to help you find what is wrong with it? If there is a problem, please explain *exactly* what the problem is.....

Comment: Sorry Again, I added more explanation

Comment: IMHO, this code shouldn't compile. You allocate your fields with 3 indices although they are defined with 4.

Comment: Stefan, Thank you, it is typo. It is 3 indices

Comment: Could you try assigning only 1-dimensional (e.g. `gpuArray(0,0,0:kmax-1)`) or 2-dimensional (e.g. `gpuArray(0,0:jmax-1,0:kmax-1)`) slices? There could be problems with your 3-dimensional approach as this might not be implemented in the CUDA API.

Comment: Can you provide a short, complete, compilable code to demonstrate?  In fact, [SO expects this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Include a statement to write out the data that you think is incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

All my apologies to the whole community. I could solve my problem. It was a silly bug I introduced in the test program. Instead of `cpuArrray= cpuArray(0:imax-1,0:jmax-1,0:kmax-1)` in the check program, I did `cpuArrray= cpuArray`.So the program was working well but the result check program was buggy.

Thank you for your follow up.

For your reference this is a part of the program (can be built and run)

```
     module mytest
   use cudafor 
   implicit none
   integer :: imax , jmax, kmax
   integer :: i,j,k
   !host arrays 
   real,allocatable:: h_a(:,:,:)
   real,allocatable:: h_b(:,:,:)
   real,allocatable:: h_c(:,:,:)

   !device array 
   real,device,allocatable:: d_b(:,:,:)
   real,device,allocatable:: d_c(:,:,:)

   real,device,allocatable:: d_b_copy(:,:,:)
   real,device,allocatable:: d_c_copy(:,:,:)

   contains 
   attributes(global) subroutine testdata()
    integer :: d_i, d_j,d_k

    d_i = (blockIdx%x-1) * blockDim%x + threadIdx%x-1
    d_j = (blockIdx%y-1) * blockDim%y + threadIdx%y-1

    do d_k = 0, 1
        d_b_copy(d_i, d_j, d_k) = d_b(d_i, d_j, d_k)

        d_c_copy(d_i, d_j, d_k) = d_c(d_i, d_j, d_k)
    end do  
   end subroutine testdata

 end module mytest 

 program Test 
   use mytest
   type(dim3) :: dimGrid, dimBlock,dimGrid1, dimBlock1
   imax = 32
   jmax = 32 
   kmax = 2

   dimGrid =  dim3(2,2, 1)
   dimBlock = dim3(imax,jmax,1)
   allocate(h_a(0:imax-1,0:jmax-1,0:1))

   allocate(h_b(0:imax-1,0:jmax-1,0:1))
   allocate(h_c(0:imax-1,0:jmax-1,0:1))  

   !real,device,allocatable::d_c(:,:,:)   
   allocate(d_b(0:imax-1,0:jmax-1,0:1))
   allocate(d_c(-1:imax,-1:jmax,-1:16))

   allocate(d_b_copy(0:imax-1,0:jmax-1,0:1))
   allocate(d_c_copy(-1:imax,-1:jmax,-1:1))

   !array initialization 
   do k = 0,kmax-1
        do j=0, jmax-1
            do i = 0, imax-1
                h_a(i,j,k) = i*0.1
            end do
        end do
    end do
   !data transfer (cpu to gpu)  
   d_b = h_a  
   d_c(0:imax-1,0:jmax-1,0:kmax-1)= h_a


   call testdata<<<dimGrid,dimBlock>>>()
  !copy back to cpu 

  h_b = d_b_copy(0:imax-1,0:jmax-1,0:kmax-1)
  h_c = d_c_copy(0:imax-1,0:jmax-1,0:kmax-1)

   !just for visual test 
   write(*,*), h_b 
   open(24,file='h_a.dat')
   write(24,*) h_a
   close(24)

   open(24,file='d_b_copy.dat')
   write(24,*) h_b
   close(24)

   open(24,file='d_c_copy.dat')
   write(24,*) h_c
   close(24)

 end program Test
```